# PdfBox PDF to Image conversion linux (issue with character spacing)

Tags: java, linux, image, pdf, pdfbox

I am using `PdfBox-1.6.0.jar` to perform a conversion of a PDF to an IMAGE (.png).
I am developing on a windows platform, but then deploying the software to a `Linux` (`Red Hat Enterprise`) server as a `RESTful` service.

I noticed a distinct character spacing difference (increase) when the code is executed on `Linux` as opposed to proper character spacing (compared to the pdf) on `Windows`.

The font is `Helvetica`. looking for clues on why there is a behavioral difference.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The rendered font looks the same? Except for the spaces?

Comment: No, they are "slightly" different, however acceptable. The character spacing is a problem because I am working with a very limited amount of horizontal space for the text to be rendered. Oddly the font "Courier" plays nice on both windows and Linux. Looking into why that is now.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe on the Linux machine the original font from the pdf file is replaced by another one at conversion time. Maybe the pdf is not using embedded font or maybe for some reason the embedded font can't be read.

Comment: @decernahoschi You are correct! I put some logging code and rebuilt the jar and ran a manual PDF to image conversions with an open source TTF font embedded as a subset in the PDF. PDFBox did not use the subset embedded font, and defaulted to a system font. I then installed my TTF font at the system level on linux and it again didn't use the embedded font, however it then was smart enough to find the font at the system level. I am now investigating why it wont use the embedded subset font. If it could use that, that would be my best case solution.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a CR-LF-thing.

On Windows, line-ends are usually encoded as CR/LF ('\r\n'), while on Linux just LF ('\n').

Answer (score 1):

PDFBox 1.6.0 still doesn't support Embedded Subset fonts and that's the reason why it's not using them to render the text in your PDF. There's an open bug for this at their issue tracker: [PDFBOX-490](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-490)